# Paper in somebody else's thesis

Tags: citations

One of my papers is only published as part of a thesis by compilation by another student.

Can I claim citations of their thesis as citations of my paper?

Is there some way I can instruct google scholar that my paper is inside of that thesis?

Clarification: I am first author on the paper. The other student is a co-author. I allowed him to publish the paper in his thesis. The other student is from another university. For a number of year, his colleagues (who I do not know) would sometimes cite our paper. After he graduated, they choose to cite his thesis instead. I cannot fault them for this, but am a bit sad to not be receiving any more citations on this paper.

Comment: Is your name on the paper? Or are you saying they plagiarised your work?

Comment: I am the first author. The other student is one of my co-authors.

Comment: Why not just publish the paper in a standard venue?

Comment: By now I have decided to do this. However, I was wondering if there also is some way to 'recover' the 'misdirected' citations.

Comment: To rephrase it as an equivalent question: if a book consisting of a number of articles (chapters) by various authors receives a citation which does not specify any chapter, to whom does the citation go? The editors?

Comment: So if I understand right, you have a paper with someone else which you never published but you complain that people cite the published thesis instead of your unpublished paper. Does this sum it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(note: I write this answer from a perspective in the biological/medical sciences, and norms about how to 'count' thesis work varies by field; however, in the fields I work in this sort of thesis where separate published or publishable papers are 'stapled together' is the norm)*

It's great that your collaborator's colleagues are going to lengths to credit their work by citing their thesis.

However, a thesis is in some ways not a full publication, isn't really peer reviewed, etc.

You should publish the paper in a more conventional way if you want it to be cited by (and read by) the broader community. Your best bet would have been to do this when the work was prepared originally (and then the thesis would have cited as well as reproduced your collaboration).

No, you can't claim citations of their thesis as your citations, you didn't author their thesis and there is a lot of other content in there that is not yours.